# HTML Button Border

Tags: html, css, button, border

I am trying to differentiate a button so that clients can see that it is the button that is in focus by default when the page loads. The design calls for a simple border around the button. I have `button` and `button1` defined in my css like so:

```css
.button {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #003366
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #003366
  border: #00ffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

The button that I am trying to focus loses the default formatting. How might I fix this so that it simply keeps its formatting, the only difference being a thicker border around the button? Also, is there a way to make the border simply wrap itself around the shape of the button instead of being a rectangular border?

Here is an image of what my buttons look like:

[image]

In this case, I am trying to focus the `Jail Address` button.

The html for the input buttons is like so:

```
<input type="reset" class="button" name="refresh" value="Refresh">
<input type="submit" class=button1 name="jail" value="Jail Address" onClick="action='JailAddresses.html'">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="action='Administrative.html'"> 
<input type="submit" class="button" name="back" value="Back" onClick="action='Administrative.html'">
```

Comment: border-color: #00ffff; - that might make a difference

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Such a silly oversight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the border by default is going to be rectangle, though with some browsers (not all) you can use the "border-radius: 5px" to get rounded corners

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

you could also just make images with the buttons you want and use them instead (png is preferred since it will keep transparency)

```
.button1 {
    background-image:url('paper.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

I use that often instead of just img src=, then you can add an "on mouseclick" with javascript.. just an option. also, the cursor can be changed so it actually looks like they're rolling over a button :)

Comment: beat me to it...and you gave more information, nice addition with the implementation details of using an image

Comment: Thanks. I guess the rounded border is not too important in this instance. I would just like to keep the default format of the `button` class and just have a border around the button. Right now, the button label has defaulted back to black (it should be blue) and the border also defaults to black (it should be red). Making an image of the button doesn't seem ideal since our web page is simply using the default HTML `button` class.

Comment: the reason that one button isn't working is because you didn't add quotes around the class .. was that intentional?

Comment: I've found that it doesn't make a difference with or without the quotes, but I added them back in just to make sure. It doesn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that setting a button `border:x` style can completely change the button rendering, at least in Safari and Firefox.  Here's a little test file I just used to demonstrate the effect:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="no border"/>
      <input type="submit" value="border:0" style="border:0;"/>
      <input type="submit" value="border:2" style="border:2;"/>
      <input type="submit" value="width:8rem" style="width:8rem;"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Rendered in Firefox on MacOS, it looks like this:

  [image: buttons example rendered in Firefox]
- and in Safari:

  [image: buttons example rendered in Safari]

So it appears that the behaviour depends on both the border value and the browser.  Seems odd to me, but there you are.  I think this explains the effect described in the original question.

Comment: In IE it is not working. So, I doubt that this solution is universal.

Answer (score 0):

The default stylings for UI elements like buttons are user-agent defined, AFAIK there isn't a border setting which will allow you to follow the contours of the button without using CSS3's [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/). Perhaps you should use a different element for your buttons that do not have a pre-defined shape, or use border-radius if appropriate, or a background image for which has the shape that you want.